# Onde é armazenada a função para a qual um lambda decaído para ponteiro aponta? Como ela é liberada?

Tags: c++, ponteiro, expressões-lambda, memória

[Eu aprendi recentemente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38621686/1941945) que posso fazer isso:

```
auto a = +[]{return true;};
a = +[]{return false;};
```

E compreendi que uma lambda que não captura nada pode decair para um ponteiro para função, [como confirmado pelo GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/abd77cfda79fc930):

`bool (*)()`

Mas aonde é armazenado o real objeto para o qual a lambda aponta? Como ele é liberado? Porque posso armazenar um ponteiro para um objeto temporário de uma lambda? Eu entendo que existe um caso exótico na linguagem no qual uma referência constante pode estender a vida de um objeto, então esperava que a conversão da lambda retornasse algo desse tipo, e não um ponteiro puro.

Comment: [Me parece](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12203426/1796236) que no armazenamento automático ("pilha"), e que ela não necessariamente decai, mas sim pode ser convertida em ponteiro para função, mas se ela pode ou não ser usada em chamadas estilo-C é dependente de implementação. Fique atento, pois o comportamento observado em uma implementação não necessariamente é o jeito que sempre vai ser.

Comment: Valeu. Estou pesquisando as respostas e parece que lambdas tem certa liberdade de implementação... Se isso se comprovar, vou pedir para você elaborar o comentário em resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(juntando informações das perguntas relacionadas sugeridas com a resposta a [réplica da pergunta no site em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38626130/1941945), cheguei a seguinte conclusão:)

Ao declarar uma lambda, o compilador gera o equivalente a um novo tipo, de nome indefinido e único, que possui um `operador()` contendo o corpo da função que a define.

Se uma lambda não captura variáveis, o C++ permite que esta decaia para um ponteiro ordinário para esta função (e esta conversão é invocada ao se aplicar o `operador+`, retornando seu endereço).

Como funções são armazenadas em área separada da memória - todas funções em C++ o são - o ponteiro permanece válido durante toda execução do programa, e a destruição da função nunca acontece (assim como uma classe nunca é destruída, apenas objetos/instâncias desta). Isto permite que se retorne, inclusive, o ponteiro para uma lambda local, [como no exemplo a seguir](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc9d87a68f5c4795):

```
#include <iostream>

bool (*cpp_newbie())()
{
    auto a = +[]{return true;};
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    auto a = cpp_newbie();
    std::cout <<  std::boolalpha << a();
}
```

Isto me pareceu contra-intuitivo num primeiro momento, mas ficou claro ao perceber que a lambda define um tipo, e o objeto `a` em questão é apenas um ponteiro para uma "função-membro", por assim dizer.

Answer (score 4):

Segundo algumas respostas em uma [pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27954634/221800) é gerado uma estrutura com os dados capturados e uma forma de acesso. Então uma instância é gerada para a *lambda* onde o dados é armazenado. [Outra pergunta interessante com teor semelhante](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16921247/221800).

A destruição ocorrerá quando a variável sair do escopo (pode ter um tempo de vida estendido dependendo de como for usado).

Em tese pode colocar um ponteiro para esse objeto, só não sei se é uma boa ideia (claro que depende do que vai fazer com ele).

Há uma [outra pergunta interessante no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12202656/221800) *linkada* pelo Pablo Almeida em comentário.

Comment: Valeu. Eu postei a pergunta lá também e as respostas (das perguntas linkadas) parecem contraditórias, vou pesquisar um pouco mais.

Comment: Como sua resposta refere-se a lambdas com estado (que capturam variáveis) e estas não podem ser convertidas para ponteiros-para-função, não se aplica a minha questão. E como o comentário do Pablo Almeida cita liberdades de implementação que, percebi, não se estendem a ponto de afetar essa garantia, elaborei minha própria resposta. Espero que não seja muito deselegante.

Comment: É bom, sempre ajuda mais pessoas.